# Remove Polygon and add a new one with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

I need to remove a Polygon I just created on a click event. When I click another again, it should remove the existing polygon and add a new one. Instead when I click it the second time it adds the second polygon but does not remove the first one.

I am using polygons in combination with Fusion Tables. The Fusion Tables remove on aclick as they should, it is just the 
Polygons that refuse.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// When the window has finished loading create our google map below
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

function init() {

    poly = "";

    // Basic options for a simple Google Map
    var mapOptions = {
        // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
        zoom: 4,
        scrollwheel: false,

        // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-15.614057, 23.351191), 

    // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
    // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');


    // Add Fusion Tables Layer
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '1rOaSNuoP1LwPf7-5j5Hr4tSWxjKT265MmuS8vd_l'
        },
        options : {suppressInfoWindows:true, clickable:false}      
    });

    layer.setMap(map);

    // Add Dynamic Markers which loads when Map loads
    function setupMarkers(){
        var locations = [
            <?php $custom_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'lodge', 'posts_per_page' => 20)); 
                $counter = 0;
                while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); $counter++; $image = get_field('page_image');?>
                ['<div class="info-popup"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><p class="lodge-rating"><?php $stars="<i class=\'fa fa-star\'></i>";$x = get_field('rating');echo str_repeat($stars, $x);?></p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"/></a><p><?php the_field('intro') ?></p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View Lodge</a></div>', <?php the_field('latitude'); ?>, <?php the_field('longitude'); ?>, <?php echo $counter; ?>],
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        ];

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }

    }
    setupMarkers()


    // Setup the Countries using the Fusion Table Data
    function setCountries(blurb, countryLat, countryLong, zoomLev) {
        layer.setMap(map);

        var options = {
            styles: []
        };
        var styles = [];

        Kenya = blurb;

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(countryLat, countryLong);

        map.setZoom(parseFloat(zoomLev));

        map.panTo(latLng);

        options.styles.push({
            where: "'name' = '" + Kenya + "'",
            polygonOptions: {
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#0000FF",
                fillOpacity: 0.3
            }
        });

        layer.setOptions(options);
    };



    // Setup the Destinations with user provided coordinates.
    function setDestinations(countryLat, countryLong, zoomLev, shapesLatArr, shapesLongArr) {

            layer.setMap(null);

            pOptions = "";

            jQuery.each(shapesLatArr, function(i, item) {
                if (i < shapesLatArr.length - 1){
                     myCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(shapesLatArr[i]) , parseFloat(shapesLongArr[i])));
                }
            });

            var polyOptions = {
                path: myCoordinates,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#0000FF",
                fillOpacity: 0.3
            };

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(countryLat, countryLong);

            map.setZoom(parseFloat(zoomLev));

            map.panTo(latLng);

            var pOptions = polyOptions;    

            poly = new google.maps.Polygon(pOptions);

            clearPoly();

            poly.setMap(map);


            myCoordinates = [];

    };

    // Clear Polygons
    function clearPoly() {
        poly.setMap(null);
    }


    // Setup the Click Events For Countries
    allCuntries = jQuery(".heatmap");

    allCuntries.each(function() {

        jQuery(this).click(function() {

            blurb = jQuery(this).text();
            countryLat = jQuery(this).attr('data-lat');
            countryLong = jQuery(this).attr('data-long');
            zoomLev = jQuery(this).attr('data-zoom');

            setCountries(blurb, countryLat, countryLong, zoomLev);
        });
    });

    // Setup the Click Events For Destinations
    allDestins= jQuery(".heatrat span");

    allDestins.each(function() {

        jQuery(this).click(function() {

            myCoordinates = [];

            shapesLat =[];
            shapesLong =[];

            countryLat = jQuery(this).attr('data-lat');
            countryLong = jQuery(this).attr('data-long');
            zoomLev = jQuery(this).attr('data-zoom');
            shapesLat = jQuery(this).attr('data-shape-lat');
            shapesLong = jQuery(this).attr('data-shape-long');

            shapesLatArr = shapesLat.split(',').map(Number);

            shapesLongArr = shapesLong.split(',').map(Number);

            setDestinations(countryLat, countryLong,zoomLev, shapesLatArr, shapesLongArr);
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: To clarify my answer is actually addressing the issue it would be useful if you could set up a https://jsbin.com/?html,js,output to serve as code we can both play with to determine the issue

Comment: Hi David thanks for the answer, I did as per below but still no luck. Check the dev link, www.weloveweb.co.za/africaandyou . I cannot setup a bin as the data is getting loaded dynamically from a DB. You can test it by scrolling to the map, clicking on South Africa, then on KwaZulu Natal, then on Cape Town, just zoom out and you will see both polygons.

Comment: See my edit - it seems that you have a problem with adding too many click listeners. How many locations are included?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including any data (some example locations) and HTML/CSS that may be required.

Comment: What polygon?  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qd4a4142/)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine from what I can see but you should declare `poly` outside the scope of the `init()` function and using:

`var poly;`

rather than:

`poly = "";`

---

There is an also an error of `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` in chrome which is suggesting that

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
})(marker, i));
```

is iterating over too many locations and adding a large number of listeners.